# navbar repeat image on both sides

Tags: html, css

I try currently to make a navbar with images, the navbar should be in middle centered with the image repeated on **both sides**. However the picture is only repeating on the right side. Anyone got a solution?

```html
#leftHalf {
   background: url(images/bg-1.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
#rightHalf {
   background: url(images/bg-2.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
```

i also found this but it is (above) only for the background, do i have to seperate the navbar in 2 container?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ea8zuad)

Thats what i got so far.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need set ul to text-align:center;

[find updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ea8zuad/3/)

```
.navbar2 ul{
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you locateganesh it worked, for some reason i got now some placeholders between the buttons seen on your updated jsfiddle. How did this happen? i didnt changed anything only the text algin center.

edit:
i got it to delete the spaces between the images.

```css
.yourclass {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In css3, you can use multiple images for background-images.
All the background-? rules can be used with the same construct.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Demo</title>
<style>
body{
    text-align: center;
}
#nav{
    background-image: url("images/battery1.jpg"), url("images/battery2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: left top, right top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav">some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try it, but you'll need your own battery pics.